How to add resources as per the role in the user token of keycloak
I have created resources in Keycloak with scopes, policies, and permissions. Now, I would like to store the resources associated with the roles in the payload of the user token based on their roles. How can I achieve this in the latest version of Keycloak?
Currently, I am setting the resource by creating a user attribute, but I am hardcoding the resource at the moment. However, I have already created resources according to the roles assigned to the user, so I want all of these resources to be included in the token.

Be aware that if JWTs have no size limit, the headers in which it is sent have in most HTTP servers. If the cardinality of the resources for a given user can be high, your solution will just not work. Also, from an architectural point of view, it seems to be a bad separation of concerns: resources should probably be the only responsibility of resource servers (authorization server should be tightly coupled only to users, not resources). Last, you'll probably be puzzled when trying to unit test your resource access policies...

@ch4mp Yes, maybe it is not the appropriate approach, but can you please tell me how can I add the associate resources in the user token as per the user role?

As stated above, I strongly advise that the authorization server puts nothing about accessed resources in tokens. It should put there only information about the resource owner (user in case of authorization code / refresh token flows, client in case of client credentials flow). This info should contain a minimum of a unique, not null,, and immutable identifier (sub claim is an excellent candidate), as well as groups, roles, permission, grants or whatever is provided by your authorization server and matches the authorities concept in Spring Security.

According to me, the resource access decision should be the responsibility of the resource server, based on the user info in the token claims (mapped to Authentication name and authorities) and, when required, on the relation between the user and accessed resources. This makes a clear separation of concerns (avoids any coupling between the authorization server and API routes or resources), and also makes access control rules pretty easy to unit test.
